# Fancybox 2.0 not loading

Tags: fancybox

I been looking and working and I can't make fancybox work in this code. I have revised severalt times and I don't understand why it doesn't work. I'm using Dreamweaver and the fancybox are marked below and I don't know if some code contrasts with the fancybox codes

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/GabLopezIT.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../images/favicon.ico" />
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>Gabriele Lopez</title>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<style type="text/css">


-->
</style>
<link href="../css/psr_site_layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../css/psr_site_layout_content.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../css/psr_site_layout_gallery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../css/psr_site_submenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->
<style type="text/css">

/*.video {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:50px;
}*/
</style>



<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    color: #FFF;
}
a:link {
    color: #CCC;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    color: #CCC;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#bio {
    margin-bottom:-20px;
}

#social {
    margin-top:5px;
    height: 25px;
    width: auto;
    float: right;

}

#lang {
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    margin-right:15px;

}
#twitter {
    float: right;
    width: 60px;
    height: 24px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin-left: 17px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#google {
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
    height: 24px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin-left: 17px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}


.fb-like {
    height: 25px;
    width: 85px;
    float: right;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin-left: 17px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display:inline-table

}



</style>
<link href="../css/copyright.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}

</script>
<link href="../css/bottom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="#666666" background="../img/background001.jpg" onload="MM_preloadImages('../images/facebook2.png')">

<!-- FACEBOOK CODE-->

<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!--END FACEBOOK CODE-->

<!--TWITTER CODE-->
<script>!function(d,s,id){
    var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if(!d.getElementById(id)){
    js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;
    js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}
    }(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>

<!--END TWITTER CODE-->

<!--GOOGLE+ CODE-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.___gcfg = {lang: 'it'};

  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
<!--END GOOGLE+ CODE-->


<div id="psr_site_layout">
<table id="Table_01" width="800" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
        <td><a href="../index.html"><img src="../img/bannerweb.png" alt="" width="800" height="200" border="0" /></a></td>

</tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
            <img src="../img/layout/PSR-website-(sliced-new)_03.png" width="800" height="8" alt="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="5"><ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
<li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="news_it.php">NEWS</a></li>
<li><a href="tour_it.php">TOUR</a></li>
<li><a href="#">FOTOS</a></li>
<li><a href="videos_it.php">VIDEOS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ALBUMS</a></li>
<li><a href="bio_it.html">BIO</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="social">
<div id="lang"><img src="../img/EN-button.png" width="20" height="20" /></div>
<div id="google"><g:plusone size="medium"></g:plusone>
</div>  
<div id="twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.gabrielelopez.com" data-text="Senti la musica di Gabriele Lopez" data-lang="it">Tweet</a></div>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.gabrielelopez.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="trebuchet ms"></div>
</div>


</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
            <img src="../img/layout/PSR-website-(sliced-new)_15.jpg" width="800" height="6" alt="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5"><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Content1" -->
```

Fancybox Scripts start here

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.0.4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=2.0.4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=2.0.4"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.4" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=2.0.4" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=2.0.4" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',

    });
});
</script>

<div id="psr_site_layout_content">
```

Fancybox HTML content starts here

```
<a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/_DjiHFxPauw" title="Vorrei tanto dirtelo"><img src="../img/tvpianeta.png"></a><p>Vorrei tanto dirtelo</p>

<a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas?autoplay=1">Youtube (iframe)</a>

<div class="video"><a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/_DjiHFxPauw" title="Vorrei tanto dirtelo"><img src="../img/tvvorrei.png"></a><p>Vorrei tanto dirtelo</p></div>

<div class="video"><a class="lavita fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/_DjiHFxPauw" title="Vorrei tanto dirtelo"><img src="../img/tvvita.png"></a>
<p>La vita che vorrei</p></div>

<div class="video"><a class="lavita fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/_DjiHFxPauw" title="Vorrei tanto dirtelo"><img src="../img/tvhistoria.png"></a><p>Historia de un perfecto idiota</p></div>

<div class="video"><a class="lavita fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/_DjiHFxPauw" title="Vorrei tanto dirtelo"><img src="../img/tvteletaxi.png"></a><p>Vorrei tanto dirtelo</p></div>
</div>

        <!-- InstanceEndEditable --></td>
    </tr>
    <div id="bottom">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
            <img src="../img/layout/PSR-website-(sliced-new)_17.jpg" width="800" height="5" alt="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="6"><div id="psr_site_submenu"><a href="index.php">Home</a> | <a href="outboard_it.html">News</a> | <a href="discografia.html">Tour</a> | <a href="media.html">Fotos</a> | Videos | <a href="contatti_it.html">Dischi</a> | <a href="www.facebook.com/pages/Poli-Studio-Recording/73432760131">Bio</a> | Cambia al Inglese</div></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td height="39" colspan="6" class="copyright">
&copy; 2012 <a href="http://www.orangeparkrecords.com">Orange Park Records srl.</a><br />
Tutti diritti riservati.
</td>
</tr>
</div>
</table>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
var MenuBar1 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar1", {imgDown:"../SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarDownHover.gif", imgRight:"../SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"});
</script>
</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
```

Comment: Beside Fancybox problem, your HTML markup is not valid (somehow obsolete), try W3C validation to find issues -> http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anywhere in your code that you have included jQuery or fancybox's css and js files.

Be sure that you have included the script and stylesheet in your document (make sure the css and js files are on your server). Make sure you also load the jQuery library.

Follow this example and adjust the paths accordingly:

```
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.4" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.0.4"></script>
```

Comment: Hello @JFK and thank you for your reply, I do not why the jQuery didn't show in my original post so I have added it back. So to answer your question jQuery and fancybox js files have been included originally. Do you know what is wrong? here is a link to the online page: http://www.gabrielelopez.com/it/videos_it.html thanks again.

Comment: You are using a relative path to link to your fancybox files so the path at the end becomes http://www.gabrielelopez.com/it/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.0.4 where the file is not found. The absolute path of the js file is http://www.gabrielelopez.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.0.4 since the fancybox folder is at the root level, not under the folder "it"

Comment: thank you and just one last thing, how can I use that with my MAMP localhost? (which is not working either)

Comment: you could leave all your code the way it is and just move the complete fancybox folder under the directory 'it'

Comment: thx JFK, I used the relative path with ../ and everything workout perfectly. Thx !

Comment: If you think I gave the right answer, please don't forget to mark this as correct. Thanks